# 'Third-party cookie will be blocked' tagged to Javascript lines?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Chrome is showing issues 'Third-party cookie will be blocked'.  I know this is part of their campaign to get rid of cookies, but can someone tell me why the error is occuring on seemingly random bits of Javascript?  You can see below the `Promise` has a red line underneath it and there are multiple warnings about this situation throughout.

This entire site uses a single cookie to save the username of the person logging in, and this particular page doesn't use cookies at all.

[image]